# Sort by latest record column from relations

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two tables (models) `Vehicle` and `Registration`. Vehicle has many registrations and every registrations has `start_date` and `expiry_date` and I need to get all vehicles with last registration sort by `expiry_date`. 
This is mine `Vehicle` model part:

```
/**
     * @return HasMany
     */
    public function registrations() :HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Registration::class);
    }

    /**
     * @return HasOne
     */
    public function activeRegistration() :HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Registration::class)->latest();
    }
```

and I try to solve like this:

```
Vehicle::with('activeRegistration')->get()->sortBy('activeRegistration.expiry_date')->take(5) // I need only 5 records
```

but this is not working as I expected. This is part of mine blade file:

```
@foreach($registrationsVehicle as $vehicle)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $vehicle->registration }}</td>
        <td>{{ $vehicle->vehicleBrand->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $vehicle->model }}</td>
        <td>{{ optional($vehicle->activeRegistration)->start_date }}</td>
        <td>{{ optional($vehicle->activeRegistration)->expiry_date }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

I get data but it's not order correctly.

Comment: You can use ORDER BY 'expiry_date'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I solve like this:

```
return Vehicle::join('registrations', 'vehicles.id','=','registrations.vehicle_id')
            ->has('activeRegistration')
            ->orderBy('registrations.expiry_date')
            ->limit(5)
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add field in `latest` method:

```php
    public function activeRegistration() :HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Registration::class)->latest('expiry_date');
    }
```

If you want to use `with('registration')`, you need to use closure like this:

```php
$vehicles = Vehicle::with(['registration' => function($relation) {
    $relation->orderBy('expiry_date', 'DESC')->first();
}])->take(5)->get();
```

For **Laravel 5.7 and onwards**

if you want to get last registration, you can just use `latest('expiry_date')`,

it will automatically convert to `order by expiry_date desc`

```php
$vehicles = Vehicle::with(['registration' => function($relation) {
    $relation->latest('expiry_date')->first();
}])->take(5)->get();
```

Comment: But activeRegistration is the last one as you can see from relationship

Comment: @knubbe You need to add field in latest method `->latest('expiry_date')`

Comment: I try all combination that you suggest but it's not working

Comment: plz use the first `$this->hasOne(Registration::class)->latest('expiry_date');`, and  `dd($vehicle->activeRegistration()->toSql())`, and then post it.

Comment: "select * from `registrations` where `registrations`.`vehicle_id` = ? and `registrations`.`vehicle_id` is not null order by `expiry_date` desc"

Comment: @knubbe It is already take the latest expiry_date  registration, r u sure it is not the latest?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204955/discussion-between-knubbe-and-tsaikoga).

Answer (score 0):

Get all then use sortBy() function in collection

```
 Vehicle::with(['activeRegistration'])
        ->all()
        ->sortByDest(function ($vehicle) {
            return $vehicle->activeRegistration->expiry_date;
        });
```